# How to group array based on key values in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array. And I have to sort this array and then have to separate it as different array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 1
            [product_type] => 1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 2
            [product_type] => 1

        )

     [2] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 1
            [product_type] => 1

        )
     [3] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 2
            [product_type] => 1

        )
)
```

I did sorting using usort

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
            return $a['brand_id'] - $b['brand_id'];
}

usort($product_details, 'sortByOrder');
```

I need to group this array based on brand_id.

The expected output is.

The name of the array also brand id.

Then I will add it to db as two different records

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 1
            [product_type] => 1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 1
            [product_type] => 1

        )
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 2
            [product_type] => 1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 2
            [product_type] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: No initially they are single array. But after sorting I need to get two arrays based on brand

Comment: what will be name of those two arrays?

Comment: The name will be brand id

Comment: Your expected output is wrong, brand id with 1 has 3 records, you are showing 2 2 each

Comment: do you mean $brand_id1, $brand_id2 etc like this? where 1 and 2 are values of branch id

Comment: opps soory I will edit that

Comment: Once check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to create dynamic array,

```
/* after your sorting logic */
$result = [];
foreach ($product_details as $key => $value) {
    // grouping data as per brand id
    $result['brand_id'.$value['brand_id']][] = $value;
}
extract($result);
print_r($brand_id1);
print_r($brand_id2);
```

[Working Demo](https://3v4l.org/4UGLY).

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 1
            [product_type] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 1
            [product_type] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 2
            [product_type] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand_id] => 2
            [product_type] => 1
        )

)
```